# How to integrate metamask logo with react website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, svg

I am new to react js and I am trying a frontend website for practice. Trying to make it look this

[image]

I want to make this svg logo follow the cursor like on the actual metamask website like [here](https://metamask.io/)

I found this codepen link  that does exactly what I want - [codepen link](https://codepen.io/shivammathur/pen/ZVJaEy)

I want to integrate this with my website but I am unable to do so as when I paste the js code gives error on my editor.

I have never used codepen before, so I am curious if there is any specific way to use it? As the code clearly runs on the website but its not working on my editor.

This is the react code I have written till now

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {
    InfoContainer,
    InfoWrapper,
    InfoRow,
    Column1,
    Column2,
    TextWrapper,
    Heading,
    Subtitle,
    ImgWrap,
    Img
  } from './experienceElements';
const InfoSection = ({
    lightBg,
    imgStart,
    lightText,
    headLine,
    img,
    alt,
    id,
    darkText,
  }) => {
    return (
        <InfoContainer lightBg={lightBg} id={id}>
            <InfoWrapper>
                <InfoRow imgStart={imgStart}>
                    <Column1>
                    <TextWrapper>
                        <Heading lightText={lightText}>{headLine}</Heading>
                        <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>1. Open a Metamask wallet - it's free</Subtitle> 
                        <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>2. Upload a picture</Subtitle> 
                        <Subtitle darkText={darkText}>3. Publish on OpenSea</Subtitle> 
                    </TextWrapper>
                    </Column1>
                    <Column2>
                        <ImgWrap>
                            <Img src={img} alt={alt} />
                        </ImgWrap>
                    </Column2>
                </InfoRow>
            </InfoWrapper>
        </InfoContainer>
    )
}

export default InfoSection
```

CSS and styled components

```
import styled from 'styled-components'


export const InfoContainer = styled.div`
color: #fff;
background: ${({ lightBg }) => (lightBg ? '#f7f8fa' : '#010606')};
height: 750px;
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  padding: 100px 0;
}
`;

export const InfoWrapper = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 24px;
  justify-content: center;
`;

export const InfoRow = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: minmax(auto, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) =>
    imgStart ? "'col2 col1'" : "'col1 col2'"};

  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-areas: ${({ imgStart }) =>
      imgStart ? `'col1' 'col2'` : `'col1 col1' 'col2 col2'`};
  }
`;

export const Column1 = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  grid-area: col1;
`;

export const Column2 = styled.div`
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  grid-area: col2;
`;

export const TextWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: 540px;
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  margin-left:50px;
`;

export const TopLine = styled.div`
  color: #01BF71;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 1.4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
`;

export const Heading = styled.h1`
color: #000;
margin-bottom: 30px;
font-size: 34px;
line-height: 1;
font-weight: 650;
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  font-size: 32px;
}
`;

export const Subtitle = styled.p`
  max-width: 440px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: ${({ darkText }) => (darkText ? '#010606' : '#f7f8fa')};
`;

export const TimeLine = styled.p`
  max-width: 440px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: ${({ darkText }) => (darkText ? '#010606' : '#f7f8fa')};
`;

export const BtnWrap = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
`;

export const ImgWrap = styled.div`
  max-width: 555px;
  height: 100%;
`;

export const Img = styled.img`
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 0;
`;
```

How can I integrate this cursor following metamask logo with my code?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/MetaMask/logo

☝️ This might help for your use-case and avoid building everything from scratch.

As to how to do it, look at the repository source code.

I haven't looked at the source code, but my guess is that the polygonal vector/3D image has an x+y offset point on the nose of the fox, that point has an eventListener checking what the x+y position is of the cursor and basically repositions the x+y offset point on the fox's nose to whatever the new x+y position is of the cursor.

Anyway, hope this helps.
Good luck with your dApp!